# How to keep the data without affect the performance in Android?

Tags: algorithm, performance, bitmap

I have array of images all image sizes are same like 1024x700 when array size is increased the application slow it's performance but i saw the another application in play store name as `FlipaClip` i don't know how it's keeps the frames but it's have nice performance i need this logic how flipaclip is store the frame data and how it's fast read the data.

Comment: Short answer, don't store images in an array. Use an image library like Picasso.  It's way easier and handles all the caching issues. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @Sabish M Library like Glide is another option which is fast in rendering the images in android.